# Access value of an element by name attribute with period

Tags: jquery

How do I get the value of a name attribute which contains a period through a variable:

I have the following example:

```
<input type="text" value="Hello!" name="input.hi" />
<input type="text" value="Goodbye" name="input.bye" />

<input type="button" data-get-value="input.hi" value="Arrive" class="greet" />
<input type="button" data-get-value="input.bye" value="Leave" class="greet" />

<script>
    $(".greet").click(function() {
        var str = $(this).attr("data-get-value").replace(/\./g, '\\\\.');
        var input = $("[name=" + str + "]").val();
        alert(input);
    });
</script>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=input\\.hi]
```

But if I run the command through my console as follows:

```
$("[name=input\\.hi]").val();
```

or

```
$("[name=input\\.bye]").val();
```

It returns the correct value.

I did searching on this board to find out how to escape the period and how to access it, but I can't get this final step to work.

Note: I cannot use another attribute like ID - it has to be name

Comment: Why you are using input.hey and input.bye ???

Comment: we are forced to do it because of the way the fields come in form the backend - have to have the period in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it on this way:

```
 $(".greet").click(function() {
        var str = $(this).attr("data-get-value");

    var input = $("[name='" + str + "']").val();
        alert(input);
    });
```

Just escape dot with single quotes, no need for replace...

http://jsfiddle.net/1pez2cyb/

Comment: Boom! Nailed it!  Thanks - I'm still new to Stack Overflow and don't have the ability to vote your answer useful - but it solved the problem - many thanks.

Comment: Np, I'm glad it helped. ;)